# Multiple Regression to suggest the number of stores needed per town/location

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, regression-coefficients

Is it possible to apply a multivariate regression to identify the number of company stores or branches required in a town or location?

1. the dependent variable is the number of stores
2. the independent variables are:

   - population count
   - location area KM2
   - number per store (traffic of current
   - per store (current stores)

Also, while these variables are separately positively correlated to the store count, when running the multivariate analysis, some of them produce negative coefficients, what does this mean?

Comment: Certainly you can *apply* regression to such data--many people have.  However, when you consider the economic mechanisms that pertain, ranging from competition to cannibalization to microeconomic optimization, it becomes apparent that a direct application of regression is unlikely to give a useful or even insightful answer except by pure luck.  Regression-like models of consumer choice have been applied more effectively, but those are very different from what you describe.

Comment: To determine the number of required stores you need first to answer how you evaluate when a store is needed. For example: Is one of them underperforming in sales? Do the current stores cover all the potential neighbourhoods of consumers? This can be a heuristic type of problem, or even an optimisation one. But linear regression is a type of [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning), in which you'd have to have the right answers beforehand (i.e. the optimal number of stores) to then find out how they're explained by different variables.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is no.

Assuming the model satisfy the [assumptions](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Multiple_linear_regression/Assumptions) and the coefficients are statistically significant, a regression using the model specification you described will *explain* the number of stores through the independent variables you used.

Which is to say it will describe how the numbers of stores varies according to population, location, etc.

Now, when a coefficient in a multivariate regression comes out negative, it means that as the corresponding independent variable increases in value, the dependent variable will decrease. For example, assume the the coefficient for `location area` happens to be negative. This means that if the area increases, the `number of stores` will decrease.